# Creating a "simple" dictionary in a Django model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, orm

Apologies for the vague title, but I'm really having trouble describing this concept.

Basically what I want is to import some json data I've created into some Django models.

My data looks like this, basically:

```
[
    {
        name: "Bingfordshire"
        results: {
            'LIB' : 23,
            'PC': 25
        },
        more dictionaries here....
    },
    more objects here....
]
```

I've setup a model for the the outer object, but I'm struggling with how to represent those interior dictionaries. My first idea was to just use fields like this:

```
class Riding:
    lib_result = models.DecimalField()
    pc_result = models.DecimalField()
```

But I have three such dictionaries and about 4 entries for each, making this a lot of typing, and a massive pain to change if I ever want to add a new entry or something.

My next idea was to use database relations:

```
class PartyResult:
    party = models.CharField()
    result = models.DecimalField()

class Riding:
    results = models.ManyToManyField(PartyResult)
```

But this adds some complexity to using it, and makes the admin site a lot less usable, and I don't want to have to do a bunch of database queries just to read one Riding. Right now, I've  realized I can use a ForeignKey in the PartyResult that leads to the riding, which does make it a bit easier, but I still feel like I'm missing some kind of solution here that doesn't need a relation at all.

I don't know too much about databases and ORMs, so I'm hoping there's some obvious solution I've missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave in and just used Django's JSONFields and Postgres. Gets me exactly what I want.